# How to design a contrast matrix with a continuous variable

Tags: matrix, lme4-nlme, contrasts

I was wondering if someone could help me designing a contrast matrix when you have a continuous variable.

My model looks like this:

```
model<-lme(Y~A*B*Days, data=data_over_time)
```

The factor A hast two levels (A1 and A2) and factor B has three levels (B1, B2, and B3). I measured the response variable Y every two or three days over 70 days (Days).

I need to look at only a few comparisons over the 70 days such us:

```
                               A1 and B1 vs A2 and B1,  
                               A2 and B2 vs A2 and B1,  
                               A1 and B2 vs A2 and B2
```

I could use the function `contrast` from the package `contrast` to design the matrix with the three comparisons mentioned above. However, I don’t know how to deal with the continuous variable Days because I need to look at the difference over the 70 days not at individual days at a time.

Any help would be much appreciated